# Compiler error when trying using std::thread

Tags: c++, multithreading

I ran into a compiler error when I tried to execute a function using std::thread. The error says : "error C2672: 'std::invoke': no matching overloaded function found".

Here is a code snippet:

```
void GetMinMax_X(const std::vector<Vertex>& iAllVertices, double & oMin_X, 
double & oMax_X)
{
    auto MinMax_X = std::minmax_element(iAllVertices.begin(), 
iAllVertices.end(), [](const Vertex& i, const Vertex& j)
    {
        return i.GetX() < j.GetX();
    });
    oMin_X = MinMax_X.first->GetX();
    oMax_X = MinMax_X.second->GetX();
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<Vertex>;
    // Some functions to fill the Vertex vector......

    double Min_X = 0;
    double Max_X = 0;
    std::thread first (GetMinMax_X, AllVertices, Min_X, Max_X);
    first.join();

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: and where is the std::invoke in the code you pasted?

Comment: Please edit your code to contain [mcve] and provide compiler error exactly as produced (you do not have to put all of them, just couple first is enough), not your interpretation of it

Comment: [`std::thread`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread) arguments are copied or moved, they cannot be references.

Comment: @Mgetz they can

Comment: @Slava only using `std::ref` please see the documentation

Comment: @Mgetz only? Is that not enough?

Comment: Note creating thread for a task and calling thread join right after that is a convoluted way of calling that task directly.

Comment: @Slava not sure what you mean by that. The OP is attempting to use reference arguments without `std::ref`.

Comment: @Mgetz then you should not say to OP that he cannot use references here, but that he/she should wrap them in `std::ref`, don't you see the difference? Btw that should not produce compile error, just results would not be propagated.

Comment: @Slava Incorrect. Compare [this](https://godbolt.org/z/1lBSHD) and [this](https://godbolt.org/z/EWpnVS).

Comment: @Slava [`std::ref`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ref) is not a reference per se, it is a reference wrapper. There is a _massive_ difference between the two. I stand by what I said.

Comment: @Mgetz using reference wrapper can OP makes results from the function to be pushed into `Min_x` and `Max_x`?

Comment: @MaxLanghof what is incorrect?

Comment: @Slava It does produce compile errors. See the first link. You can't form references to the copies (because they are temporaries I believe). Which is good, because it protects unwary users from this unexpected seam. I would've probably fallen for that too.

Comment: Adding std::ref for the two output variables seems to solve the problem. Thanks!

Comment: @MaxLanghof I see, I mixed that with `std::function` I think, which hapilly binds copy to a ref

Comment: @Slava `std::function` works flawlessly with plain references. I don't understand in what context it would bind a copy to a ref?

Comment: @MaxLanghof I meant `std::bind` sorry tough morning - http://cpp.sh/3n57u

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ -- `std::invoke` is buried inside the implementaiton of the constructor for `std::thread`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error comes up because `std::thread` uses `std::invoke` behind the scenes to invoke `GetMinMax_X`, but with the arguments copied/moved. In particular, you [cannot](https://godbolt.org/z/1lBSHD) use

```
void GetMinMax_X(const std::vector<int>& iAllVertices, double & oMin_X, double & oMax_X)
```

because you would be forming references to the copies, which is not what you want.

You [could still use](https://godbolt.org/z/EWpnVS)

```
void GetMinMax_X(const std::vector<int>& iAllVertices, const double & oMin_X, const double & oMax_X)
```

but that would not help you get back the values into the main thread.

The solution is to use `std::ref`:

```
std::thread first(GetMinMax_X, AllVertices, std::ref(Min_X), std::ref(Max_X));
```

https://godbolt.org/z/ClK3Cb

See also what cppreference has to say about `std::thread` (where this "limitation" and the workaround are described):

> https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread
>
> The arguments to the thread function are moved or copied by value. If a reference argument needs to be passed to the thread function, it has to be wrapped (e.g. with std::ref or std::cref).
>
> Any return value from the function is ignored. If the function throws an exception, std::terminate is called. In order to pass return values or exceptions back to the calling thread, std::promise or std::async may be used.

Comment: Adding std::ref seems to make the compiler happy. Thank you for your explanation!